# Polymer paper-dialog on iOS

Tags: polymer

I am having a weird issue with Polymer paper-dialog on Safari iOS, working nice on desktop. The overlay seems to be under the backdrop element so the overlay is not accessible. 
I have been reading this question 
[paper-dialog in Polymer doesn't close in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075990/paper-dialog-in-polymer-doesnt-close-in-iphone) 
and the proposed solution doesn't work for me.

The thing is that when I try the dialog in the polymer-project element page it works on iOS but my implementation doesn't, but I can't find any differences between my implementation and the provided demo https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dialog

I have put my page in an accesible url so you can try it

http://v5.irekia.efaber.net/mobile/test

If I try it from my Safari desktop it works fine, but in my iPhone the backdrop element is over the overlay

[image: overlay in iPhone fails]
Could someone help me? Am I missing something?

Comment: It is currently still an [issue](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior/pull/155) with the iron-overlay-behavior and stacking context. In the meantime, you can try to apply this [patch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31510980/1015489) to all of your dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping the the z-index of your paper-dialog to 105. The `<iron-overlay-backdrop>` element has some limitations:

> The element is styled to appear on top of other content by setting its
>   z-index property. You must ensure no element has a stacking context
>   with a higher z-index than its parent stacking context. You should
>   place this element as a child of  whenever possible.

Source:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-overlay-behavior

Answer (score -1):

Polymer is not fully supported on some browser yet.
Try to update the webcomponents.js or update the paper-dialog component.